# O que é um Script Kiddie?

Tags: terminologia

Vi esse termo em um filme, *Who Am I (Invasores em PT-BR)*, e basicamente o que entendi é uma atribuição aos famosos `ctrl c + ctrl v`.

Para especificar melhor, quais ações fazem uma pessoa ser considerada um `script kiddie`? Um `script kiddie` é odiado por programadores? E no geral, o que é um `script kiddie`  ?

Comment: Se alguém souber tags que são referentes a pergunta, peço que edite a pergunta por favor.

Comment: Use terminologia

Comment: Dê uma pesquisada em proteção de código PHP, HTML e JS aqui no site que vai ter um prato cheio de técnicas compatíveis com esse _modus operandi_.

Comment: Escolha uma resposta para sua pergunta.

Comment: @durtto o problema é que todas as respostas são apenas a definição da palavra de uma forma bem resumida, o que queria assim como coloquei na pergunta, seria meio que uma resposta mais aprofundada sobre esse assunto.

Comment: mas para não deixar sem uma resposta marcada como correta, marcarei a com mais upvote

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Script kiddie é o termo usado para pessoas que utilizam scripts, código fontes, exploits ou outros tipos de artefatos sem ter a menor noção de como eles funcionam, seu uso é na base do erro/acerto(força bruta), geralmente com o proposito de invadir ou causar danos a redes/sistemas.

Answer (score 11):

O @rray já te deu a definição exata sobre o termo, mas vale lembrar que na minha época (falando assim estou me achando um ancião), antes de existir `windows 3.11` e `windows 95`, pessoas com baixo nível de conhecimento e que utilizavam programas e scripts sem ter conhecimento de como seus algoritmos funcionam eram conhecidos como `Lammers`, portanto ambos são sinônimos, eventualmente você poderá escutar os dois termos.

Comment: wuala!!! puxou da raiz... fazia mais ou menos uns 20 anos que eu não via esse termo. anciao++;    :D

Answer (score 8):

> Script Kiddie é o nome atribuído de maneira depreciativa aos crackers inexperientes que procuram alvos fáceis para aplicar seus poucos conhecimentos técnicos. Eles não possuem conhecimento de programação e têm como objetivo ganhar fama e lucros pessoais com seus ataques.

E na verdade, são "odiados" pela maioria dos hackers.